# How to POST Payload using requests library to Flask app from another Python App

Tags: flask, python-requests

I have two apps, a **flask app**(*app.py*) as my interface, and another app that integrates with a usb barcode scanner and sends a post request to the Flask route, lets call this **scanner app** (*scanner.py*).

What I wanted to happen is that when the scanner successfully scans a barcode, supposedly it should have sent a post reqeusts to the route with a payload, and the payload should have been received by the flask app.

But I think this is incorrect since nothing happens after the scan.

**scanner.py**

```
def UPC_lookup(api_key,upc):
    '''V3 API'''

    try:

        item, value = search_request(upc)
        print str(item) + ' - ' + str(value)
        payload = {}
        payload['item'] = str(item)
        payload['price'] = str(value)
        payload_data = json.dumps(payload)
        requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', data=payload_data)

    except Exception as e:
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            UPC_lookup(api_key,barcode_reader())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

**app.py**

```
# Index route
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = request.args.get('item')
        price = request.args.get('price')
        print(str(item))
        print(str(price))
        return render_template('dashboard.html', item=item, value=price)
    return render_template('dashboard.html') #ICO Details
```

What I wanted to happen is that when it scans a barcode and sends a post request, the payload should have been received and is shown to the dashboard, however im receiving nothing.

Is there a workaround for this? or perhaps a much better implementation?

Comment: Did you try to see if any exceptions were being thrown? As it is, your exceptions are being ignored. Log your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use request.form instead of request.args.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = request.form.get('item') # <-- Here!
        price = request.form.get('price')
        print(str(item))
        print(str(price))
        return render_template('dashboard.html', item=item, value=price)
    return render_template('dashboard.html') #ICO Details
```